# Agenda eventos mensuales

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando crear un calendario mensual que al hacer click en un dia determinado, me lleve a ese dia con sus eventos. El problema es que no se cómo enganchar este calendario mensual para que me lleve a la página diaria, no sé si me explico correctamente. Lo estoy haciendo con javascript, html y css. Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me gustaria que al clicar en un dia, me lleve a otro archivo que tengo mostrando el dia seleccionado.

Os dejo el código en js:

```js
var actual=new Date();
function mostrarCalendario(year,month)
{
 var now=new Date(year,month-1,1);
 var last=new Date(year,month,0);
 var primerDiaSemana=(now.getDay()==0)?7:now.getDay();
 var ultimoDiaMes=last.getDate();
 var dia=0;
 var resultado="<tr bgcolor='silver'>";
 var diaActual=0;
 console.log(ultimoDiaMes);

 
 var last_cell=primerDiaSemana+ultimoDiaMes;
 
 // hacemos un bucle hasta 42, que es el máximo de valores que puede
 // haber... 6 columnas de 7 dias
 for(var i=1;i<=42;i++)
 {
  if(i==primerDiaSemana)
  {
   // determinamos en que dia empieza
   dia=1;
  }
  if(i<primerDiaSemana || i>=last_cell)
  {
   // celda vacia
   resultado+="<td class='ayer'>"+dia+"</td>";
  }else{
   // mostramos el dia
   if(dia==actual.getDate() && month==actual.getMonth()+1 && year==actual.getFullYear())
    resultado+="<td class='hoy'>"+dia+"</td>";
   else
    resultado+="<td>"+dia+"</td>";
   dia++;
  }
  if(i%7==0)
  {
   if(dia>ultimoDiaMes)
    break;
   resultado+="</tr><tr>\n";
  }
 }
 resultado+="</tr>";
 
 
 
 var meses=Array("ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "OCTUBRE", "NOVIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE");
 

 
 // Calculamos el siguiente mes y año
 nextMonth=month+1;
 nextYear=year;
 if(month+1>12)
 {
  nextMonth=1;
  nextYear=year+1;
 }
 
 // Calculamos el anterior mes y año
 prevMonth=month-1;
 prevYear=year;
 if(month-1<1)
 {
  prevMonth=12;
  prevYear=year-1;
 }
 
 //document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+meses[month-1]+" / "+year+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div>";
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML=resultado;
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+year+"</div><div>"+meses[month-1]+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div><div>"+meses[month-3]+"</div><div>"+meses[month+1]+"</div><div>"+meses[month-2]+"</div><div>"+meses[month]+"</div>";
 
}
 
mostrarCalendario(actual.getFullYear(),actual.getMonth()+3);
```

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>

 <!--http://www.lawebdelprogramador.com-->

 <title>Ejemplo de un simple calendario en JavaScript</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <style>

  #calendar {

   font-family:Arial;

   font-size:12px;

  }

  #calendar caption {

   text-align:left;

   padding:5px 10px;

   background-color:#003366;

   color:#fff;

   font-weight:bold;

   font-size:medium;

  }

  #calendar caption div:nth-child(1) {float:left;}

  #calendar caption div:nth-child(2) {float:right;}

  #calendar caption div:nth-child(2) a {cursor:pointer;}

  #calendar th {

   background-color:#006699;

   color:#fff;

   width:40px;

  }

  #calendar td {

   text-align:right;

   padding:2px 5px;

   background-color:silver;

  }

  #calendar .hoy {

   background-color:red;

  }

 </style>

</head>

 

<body>

 

<h1>Ejemplo de un simple calendario en JavaScript</h1>

<table id="calendar">

 <caption></caption>

 <thead>

  <tr>

   <th>Lun</th><th>Mar</th><th>Mie</th><th>Jue</th><th>Vie</th><th>Sab</th><th>Dom</th>

  </tr>

 </thead>

 <tbody>

 </tbody>

</table>

 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola, podias mostrar lo que tienes conseguido. Si no sabes como, [aparte del recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)  que veo habras echo por tu medalla, pues ver mas partes para ayudarte a [formular una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y seguro que hay alguien dispuesto a ayudarte. Suerte

Comment: He añadido una imagen con lo que tengo, no se si es suficiente

Comment: Hola! Para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad es indispensable que leas **[ask]** y también que agregues un **[mcve]**

Comment: Si quieres que te ayuden repasate los enlaces que te ofrece @KacosPro

Comment: Creo que ahora se puede ver mejor, he dejado el código en js. Gracias

Comment: aádido lo que faltaba de HTML original desde https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/JavaScript/4062-Calendarios-en-JavaScript.html

Answer (score -1):

Aunque no has colocado el codigo de como construyes el calendario con js, se me ocurre le agregues el evento al dia seleccionado

```
losdiasdelcalendario.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //la funcion que quieres utilizar, en tu caso ir a la pagina deseada;
});
```

Si es con HTML puedes usar:

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

Espero te sirva de guia por donde empezar...

Comment: He dejado el código en js pero aparece muy desordenado, no se si te puede servir para que le eches un vistazo...de todas formas muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Échale un ojo!!! https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer:

Comment: Creo que esta bien ya el código, solo necesitaría saber como enlazar cada uno de los días con otro js que tengo. Gracias